# Install Android studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I had Android Studio 1.0 version. Using Check for updates link, I downloaded version 2.0. Updates link directed me to android canary link and the zip file is downloaded. The zip folder does not contain any install link. How should I update my existing IDE ?

Comment: Just extract the contents of the zip file to an appropriate location.Voila! It's installed.

Comment: Just keep in mind that this is not a final version and there is a possibility that there could be bugs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a folder called bin. Inside there should be a file called studio.exe or studio64.exe(if you are using Windows 64 bits). Simply click the appropiated file.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Stable version just got released

You can download from official site or try to update from help->check for update
in your previous Android studio.

Once it get downloaded go to bin folder of latest downloaded Android studio
and run studio64.exe for 64 bit machine

Bonus:
A new Emulator comes with the Latest Android Studio IDE

Here is [good post to check installing it](http://androidgreeve.blogspot.in/2016/04/Android-Studio-installing-and-refrence.html) with some good list of shoortcuts to make it more productivity

Answer (score -1):

You should download the update from the Beta channel, and Android Studio will install it for you automatically.

Answer (score -1):

you don't have to update the existing IDE you can run studio application in bin folder from extracted file